# Displaying values from one form in another form on the page before the user clicks the submit button

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am new to php.I want to perform form cascading.
i will be having form like registration form,where if i enter any data in text-fields it should be automatically displayed in another form before the submit button is clicked.

Please if anybody knows help me,
I am in need.

Comment: sounds more like javascript than php

Comment: might be....i dont know exactly what i need to use here....please  anybody post some examples ........here is a perfect example on this..http://www.vistaprint.com/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?pf_id=064&combo_id=120585&free_studio_gallery=true&referer=http%3a%2f%2fwww.vistaprint.com%2fvp%2fwelcome.aspx%3fxnav%3dwelcomeback%26rd%3d2&rd=2

Answer (score 1):

A little Javascript will do the trick.  It will be easy if you use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to help you out.  Just bind each field in your form to the *change* event using the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method, and then update the "cascaded" field to the value passed to the change() method.

For example, consider the HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="field1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And supposed you want to update the following div dynamically as the above form is edited:

```
<div id="field1_val"></div>
```

Add the following script to the head of your HTML:

```
//This will just make sure you're using the awesomeness of jQuery...
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

//This will bind your field to the change event using jQuery
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#field1").change( function() {
    $("#field1_val").text($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.